# How do I connect a Samsung Original Stylus Touch S Pen to a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4?

Tags: tablet

I recently bought my wife a new tablet - she is an artist and is looking to draw on the new screened tablet.  I also got her a pen so that she could do this.

The Tablet I got her was a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 and the pen I got her was a Samsung Original Stylus Touch S Pen for Samsung Galaxy Note 4.

Is there any way for me to connect this pen to the tablet? Or do I need to get a different pen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nope.

### A Samsung Original Stylus Touch S Pen for Samsung Galaxy Note 4 will not work on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

The Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 has a capacitive digitizer; not an active digitizer that the Samsung Original Stylus Touch S Pen requires.

[This review](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-does-samsungs-s-pen-work-so-damn-well) states the issue; bold emphasis is mine:

> **The S Pen is an inductive stylus. The display on the Note has what's called an active digitizer under the glass.** When the S Pen gets close to the screen, the magnetic field of the active digitizer induces a current that powers its internal circuitry. Power is passed here just like a wireless charging mat and phone that supports its work, it's just not inducing nearly as much power.

And this too; again bold emphasis is mine:

> This is far more accurate than a capacitive stylus could ever be. **It's why the S Pen won't work as a stylus on any other phone — it's not an electrical conductor.** It's also why the S Pen, or Apple Pen, or Pixel Pen, or Surface Pen, etc. work so much better than a "regular" stylus.

Comment: Thank you - it seems I made the mistake of not realizing that a "Galaxy Note" is a smartphone, not a tablet.  Looks like we'll have to return the pen I got and purchase one that works with the Galaxy S4 - Which also explains why this one was much less expensive than the others I saw when browsing before.